# deleting a row from a listbox Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox that shows up the rows of an excel sheet i need to add a delete button to delete the selected row. i tried this

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    If lstDisplay.Selected(i) Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

but when i try to delete for example the the row 10 it's the 9 that gets deleted it always delets the line before the one selected

any fix ???

Thanks everyone

Comment: Because listbox array is 0 based, so you have to add 1 to the row number to match excel 1 based rows. So, `Rows(i+1).EntireRow.Delete` will work. No need to select and delete in 2 lines

Comment: Also, try to avoid `Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row` as it's a bit 2003ish. Nowadays we use variants of `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` combined with a `With Worksheets("sheetname")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll have to test this myself, but I guess something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim i As Long, rng As Range
With Me.lstDisplay
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Union(rng, Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i + 1))
            Else
                Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

rng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

That way you'll only have to perform deleting rows once.

Btw, I anticipated a multiselect listbox. If it's not a multiselect it would simplify the code as there is no need to loop the listbox.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you this :

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    If lstDisplay.Selected(i) Then
        Rows(i).Delete
        i = i - 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Also **Note** that `Rows(i).Delete` is exactly the same as `Rows(i).Select Selection.Delete` Excepted that `Select` should be avoided as much as possible

As said [@BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) :

You can use the "Option Base 1" declaration at the top of a code module to change the default lower bound to 1 instead of 0.
For exemple :

```
Option Base 1 

Dim arValues(10) As String       'contains 10 items (not 11)
```

[Option Base Doc Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement)

Comment: Did you see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993207/deleting-a-row-from-a-listbox-userform#comment102393163_57993207)? `Rows(i)` will not work when `i` = 0. Also, when deleting rows, you want to start from the end and work up. Also - don't modify `i` within the loop.

Comment: Note that changing it to `For i = 1` doesn't work either, because the listbox array is 0-based so now you're skipping the first element.

Comment: @BigBen I agree with `i = 0` but you can also delete rows starting at the top to the bot of the sheet, just need to set i = i - 1 each time you delete a row

Comment: Modifying `i` within the loop is a *bad* practice. Don't. Loop backwards with `Step -1`. And your latest edit is still problematic. Or only delete once, as the other posted answer proposes.

Comment: @BigBen for the array the OP just got to add `Option Base 1 ` at the top of his code

Comment: @BigBen I edited my answer do you approve this Idea?