# I am getting an an invalid argument error VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

The goal with this code is to delete the corresponding spreadsheet row as that which is selected in a listbox control. When I highlight my cursor in the IDE over the code of each line in the 'For...Next' loop, the tooltip indicates the properly assigned object/data. I also replaced the variable 'i' with a constant (for example, used the number 13), and the iterator works. However, a runtime invalid argument error is being generated at the
'If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then' line. Please, examine and advised. The statement for actually deleting my row has not been entered yet as I would like to include a message box that asks the user if they are sure they want to delete the row and also a confirmation that the row was indeed deleted.

Also, I understand that using variables can help simply code, but here, are variable even necessary?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim rngDelete As Range
Dim wksActivityForm As Worksheet

Set wksActivityForm = Worksheets("Activity Form")
Set rngDelete = wksActivityForm.Range("ActivityTbl")

wksActivityForm.Activate
For i = 0 To rngDelete.Rows.Count
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
    rngDelete.Rows(i).Select
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: [Helpful comment in the linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993207/deleting-a-row-from-a-listbox-userform#comment102393163_57993207).

Comment: When I changed the variable 'i' to a constant, it worked; however, I am getting an invalid argument error. Is there something wrong with my code as far as the variables and how they are implemented?

Comment: `ListBox` is zero-based. `Rows` is one-based. So you need an offset. But you really should use `Union` here when deleting, as demonstrated in the linked thread.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with deleting rows from a listbox. My question explicitly asked about an invalid argument error. There is nothing wrong with my code as far the logic. For some odd reason, I decided to set my Multiselect property for my listbox to option 2 (frmMultiSelectEextended). This seems to be what was causing my invalid argument error, considering that after changing it to option 0 (frmMultiSelectSingle), the code executed as desired, minus starting my iterator from 0 instead of 1, which of course gives an offset of -1.

Comment: As mentioned previously `ListBox` is zero-based and `Rows` is one-based so you need to make sure you account for that. You're currently using `Rows.Count` to get the highest index, which causes the invalid argument in `ListBox1.Selected(i)`. Furthermore `Rows(i)` is invalid if `i`=`0`. The linked question shows you how to loop over the items in the listbox correctly, and also shows you how to use `Union` when deleting, which is probably the best practice here. Note the comment in the linked thread: If it's not a multiselect it would simplify the code as there is no need to loop the listbox.

Comment: `ListBox1.Selected(i)` should return the current iteration of `(i)` over the loop, right? Instead of me guessing I researched the MultiSelect property of the Form Control. When the MultiSelect property is set to Extended or Multi, the Value property of the of the control apparently is set to Null, which would explain why an invalid argument is thrown at the `ListBox1.Selected(i)` line...essentially, instead of an integer being passed, the argument for the Selected property is null. I now understand the multiselect logic. I will include the new code above. I will also experiment with `Union`.

Comment: `Listbox1.Selected(i)` returns a *boolean*. It is entirely separate from the value of the listbox. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-determine-the-items-that-are-selected-in-a-listbox-control-7ad04b22-65ac-5f8d-1d3b-b774e2aa0d98

Comment: I was about to delete my comment. Yes...I'm learning...